# Embeding google maps in web page outputs Error message - Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null

Tags: api, google-api, geolocation, geocoding, google-geolocation

Question: Embeding google maps in web page outputs Error message - Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null

Answer: It is very simple. The Js code InitMap function requires to be code below to the HTML div tag. InitMap function needs the div to generate map first when the page load and there the hierarchy should look like HTML code above then JS code related to geolocation API.

Answer (score 1):

> HTML code above then JS code

If using `async`, the script loading google maps should be below necessary HTML in `<body>`. If `defer`, it can be in `<head>`.

If neither `async` or `defer`, it must be after the necessary elements in `<body>`.

For more information, refer to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API.